# R dbplyr mysql column conversion

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, dbplyr

I have a table in mySQL that looks something like this:

```
tbl<-tibble(
   Result=c("0.1","<0.0001","1.1"),
   Unit=c("mg/L","ug/L","mg/L"),
   Pref_Unit=c("mg/L","mg/L","mg/L"),
   Conversion=c(1,1000,1)
)
```

What I would like to do using `dbplyr`, `pool`, and `RMariaDB` is to convert the `Result` column to the preferred unit using the conversion factor in the table, while preserving the "<", and also splitting the Result column into a `numeric` fraction containing only the number and `censored` indicating whether the `Result` contained a "<".

With regular `dplyr`, I would do something like this:

```
tbl<-tbl %>%
    mutate(numb_Result=as.numeric(gsub("<","",Result)),
           cen_Result=grepl("<",Result)) %>%
    mutate(new_Result=ifelse(cen_Result,paste0("<",numb_Result*Conversion),paste0(numb_Result*Conversion)))
```

But that doesn't work with the database table. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Simon!

I had found a similar solution which does work on the actual SQL database environment (note that I also had to pass the column name as a variable `result_col`, hence the use of `!!sym()`):

```
tbl %>%
mutate(numb_res = REGEXP_REPLACE(!!sym(result_col),"<",""), 
       cen_res = !!sym(result_col) %like% "<%") %>%
      mutate(numb_res=numb_res*Conversion) %>%
      mutate(!!result_col:=case_when(
        cen_res==1 ~ paste0("<",numb_res),
        T ~ paste0(numb_res)
      ))
```

It seems you are correct that there is no SQL translation for `as.character()` and `as.numeric()`, but just doing the multiplication on the character vector is enough to make it numeric, and similarly, pasting the values with "<" make its back into a character.

I think this is working for me, but I will investigate your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is most likely because dbplyr does not have translations defined for `gsub` and `grepl`. A couple of possibilities for you to test below:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)

tbl<-tibble(
  Result=c("0.1","<0.0001","1.1"),
  Unit=c("mg/L","ug/L","mg/L"),
  Pref_Unit=c("mg/L","mg/L","mg/L"),
  Conversion=c(1,1000,1)
)

remote_table = tbl_lazy(tbl, con = simulate_mssql())

remote_table %>%
  mutate(has_sign = ifelse(substr(Result, 1, 1) == "<", 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(removed_sign = ifelse(has_sign == 1, substr(Result, 2, nchar(Result)), Result)) %>%
  mutate(num_value = as.numeric(removed_sign)) %>%
  mutate(converted = as.character(1.0 * num_value * Conversion)) %>%
  mutate(new_Result = ifelse(has_sign, paste0("<",converted), converted))
```

There are dbplyr translations for `ifelse`, `substr`, `nchar`, `as.numeric`, `as.character`, and `paste0`. So I expected this to work. However, I keep getting an error because the translator requires the `start` and `stop` arguments to `substr` to be constants and hence it does not like me passing `nchar(Results)` as an argument. But this might be fixed in a more recent version of the package.

My second attempt:

```r
remote_table %>%
  mutate(has_sign = ifelse(substr(Result, 1, 1) == "<", 1, 0),
         character_length = nchar(Result),
         remove_first = sql(REPLACE(Result, "<", ""))) %>%
  mutate(removed_sign = ifelse(has_sign == 1, remove_first, Result)) %>%
  mutate(num_value = as.numeric(removed_sign)) %>%
  mutate(converted = as.character(1.0 * num_value * Conversion)) %>%
  mutate(new_Result = ifelse(has_sign, paste0("<",converted), converted))
```

This produces the expected SQL translation. But as I am using a simulated database connection, I have not been able to test whether it returns the expected output. The downside of this approach is that it used the SQL function `REPLACE` directly (it passes untranslated into the SQL code), which is less elegant than a fully translated solution.

There are probably more elegant ways to do this. But hopefully between these two you can find a suitable solution.